# SaltStack: dockerng is not available

Tags: docker, salt-stack

I'm quite new to SaltStack. I've setup a salt-master and a salt-minion (via salt-cloud on my ESXi). It works fine so far. However, I cannot get dockerng to run any function on my minion. It always returns `'dockerng.xxxx' is not available`:

```
# salt '*' test.ping
minion1:
    True

$ salt '*' dockerng.version
minion1:
    'dockerng.version' is not available.
```

However, When I call the same with salt-call directly on the minion:

```
$ salt-call dockerng.version
[INFO    ] Determining pillar cache
local:
    ----------
    ApiVersion:
        1.23
```

Any hints/ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the python docker module on the minion itself? That's a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered exactly the same situation. Installing 'docker-py' on the salt-master worked for me. Of course, as suggested by Utah_Dave, docker-py would also be needed on any minion that would be targeted by dockerng.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem while using an image with docker pre-installed. The solution that works for me is to restart the `salt-minion` daemon:

```
salt-minion:
  pkg:
    - installed
    - name: salt-minion
  service.running:
    - enable: True
    - require:
      - pkg: salt-minion
      - service: docker
      - pip: docker-py
    - watch:
      - pip: docker-py
```

taken from http://humankeyboard.com/saltstack/2013/how-to-restart-salt-minion.html

Unfortunately, the dockerng module doesn't work until the second run from the master. I'm still playing with `watch` and `reload_modules` trying to get this to work.

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/index.html#reloading-modules